# FragmentActivity cannot be converted to ConnectionCallbacks

Tags: android

So I'm trying to implement a Google Map view into a Fragment and then display the user's current location on it. I'm having a bit of trouble with getting the Context variables right since I am working on a Fragment and not an activity. I'm using *getActivity()* and container.getContext() instead of *this* in order to get it working with the Fragment and it's not giving me an error anywhere except for one place. Here is my approach, I'm only pasting in the relevant methods:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment by using global mView
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        fragment_context = container.getContext();
        return mView;
    }


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(getActivity()) //ERROR
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error on my call to addConnectionCallbacks() which tells me:

```
Error:(112, 52) error: incompatible types: FragmentActivity cannot be converted to ConnectionCallbacks
```

If you want to see the full source code, you can look [here](http://pastebin.com/CusUbjMs). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .addConnectionCallbacks(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your `FragmentActivity` but im guessing it does not have `implements ConnectionCallbacks`. If it does you simply just need to cast it

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks((ConnectionCallbacks)getActivity()) //ERROR
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(ConnectionCallbacks)getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Comment: It implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks as you can see in the code I pasted in my post.

Comment: @FlameDra yes your `MainFragment` does, but your are not passing in that. You are passing in your activity, which is whatever is hosting the fragment. If you want the callbacks to be handled by the fragment, then simply use `this`